# Meteor JS: Pnotify/Jquery package compatibility - NPM error when trying to import

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, pnotify

Wondering if anyone on here has gotten pnotify to work; I am getting the following error (on the server, when building) when trying to use the npm package:

`import pnotify from 'pnotify';`

`Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
 at module.exports (...\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:31:12)
 at s (...\node_modules\pnotify\dist\pnotify.js:6:386)`

I'm guessing it has to do with the jquery dependency?

`-- pnotify@3.2.0
  -- jquery@3.2.1`

I am using BlazeLayout if it makes a difference...

I have also tried using the atmosphere package, to no avail
import { PNotify } from 'meteor/s2corp:pnotify'

Any ideas?

Comment: I used to use `pnotify` and didn't notice any problems. One thing is I imported additional styles and js at startup like `import 'pnotify/dist/pnotify.css'; import 'pnotify/dist/pnotify.mobile.js';`

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the suggestion. Will keep it in mind as I look into it, though it doesn't seem to solve it. For now, I have found a way to import the existing package and use it...though would love to be able to import the npm package directly, as it is kept up to date.

Answer (score 1):

For minimal notifications:

Add `pnotify`:

```
meteor npm install --save pnotify
```

Import all necessary files and `PNotify` itself:

```
import PNotify from 'pnotify'
import 'pnotify/dist/pnotify.css';
```

Show notifiction:

```
new PNotify({
  title: 'Regular Notice',
  text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
});
```

All together in default meteor bare app:

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import PNotify from 'pnotify'
import 'pnotify/dist/pnotify.css';

import './main.html';

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Template.instance().counter.get();
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    new PNotify({
      title: 'Regular Notice',
      text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
    });
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
  },
});
```